Vega kibana node graph with mesh
We are currently working on a node graph.
We are sending mqtt msg over an esp to kibana and there we want to visualize a graph of basically what node is connected with which node.
and our msgs have the following structure:
{"sensors":[{"name":"N1_MESH_Sensor", "values":[{"timestamp":1720442110210, "edges":[{"from":"N1", "to":"NMOCK1"}], "remove":"0"}]}]}

and when a node disconnects the following msg will be send:
 {"sensors":[{"name":"N1_MESH_Sensor", "values":[{"timestamp":1720442118144, "edges":[{"from":"null", "to":"NMOCK1"}], "remove":"1"}]}]}

so basically we set the parent to "null" and then also a remove flag to 1.
what works till now is that the graph is shown on kibana.
but the nodes are not being deleted when the child disconnects from our mesh net.
any ideas what we could change here:
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "Display network graph from Elasticsearch data with edge labels",
  "autosize": "none",
  "width": 700,
  "height": 400,
  "padding": 5,
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "cx",
      "update": "width / 2"
    },
    {
      "name": "cy",
      "update": "height / 2"
    },
    {
      "name": "nodeRadius",
      "value": 20
    },
    {
      "name": "nodeCharge",
      "value": -15
    },
    {
      "name": "linkDistance",
      "value": 80
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "sensorData",
      "url": {
        "index": "25_36_170",
        "body": {
          "size": 1000,
          "sort": [{"timestamp": {"order": "desc"}}],
          "_source": ["sensor_name", "timestamp", "value.edges"],
          "query": {
            "range": {
              "timestamp": {
                "gte": "now-1d/d",
                "lt": "now"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "format": {
        "property": "hits.hits"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "flattenedEdges",
      "source": "sensorData",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "flatten",
          "fields": ["_source.value.edges"],
          "as": ["edges"]
        },
        {
          "type": "project",
          "fields": ["_source.sensor_name", "_source.timestamp", "edges.from", "edges.to", {"field": "edges.remove", "as": "remove", "type": "boolean"}],
          "as": ["sensor_name", "timestamp", "edge_from", "edge_to", "remove"]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "removeInt",
          "expr": "datum.remove ? 1 : 0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "validEdges",
      "source": "flattenedEdges",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "datum.edge_from !== 'null' && datum.edge_from !== null && datum.edge_from !== '' && datum.removeInt === 0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "nodes",
      "source": "validEdges",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": ["edge_from"]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "id",
          "expr": "datum.edge_from"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "label",
          "expr": "datum.edge_from"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "targetNodes",
      "source": "validEdges",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": ["edge_to"]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "id",
          "expr": "datum.edge_to"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "label",
          "expr": "datum.edge_to"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "combinedNodes",
      "source": ["nodes", "targetNodes"],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": ["id", "label"]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "x",
          "expr": "random() * width"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "y",
          "expr": "random() * height"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "edges",
      "source": "validEdges",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "lookup",
          "from": "combinedNodes",
          "key": "id",
          "fields": ["edge_from"],
          "as": ["sourceNode"]
        },
        {
          "type": "lookup",
          "from": "combinedNodes",
          "key": "id",
          "fields": ["edge_to"],
          "as": ["targetNode"]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "sourceX",
          "expr": "datum.sourceNode.x"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "sourceY",
          "expr": "datum.sourceNode.y"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "targetX",
          "expr": "datum.targetNode.x"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "targetY",
          "expr": "datum.targetNode.y"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "nodesToRemove",
      "source": "flattenedEdges",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "datum.removeInt === 1"
        },
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": ["edge_from"],
          "fields": ["edge_from"],
          "ops": ["distinct"],
          "as": ["node_id"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "filteredNodes",
      "source": "combinedNodes",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "datum.id !== 'null' && datum.id !== null && datum.id !== ''"
        },
        {
          "type": "lookup",
          "from": "nodesToRemove",
          "key": "node_id",
          "fields": ["id"],
          "as": ["removeNode"]
        },
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "!datum.removeNode"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "line",
      "from": {
        "data": "edges"
      },
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "stroke": {
            "value": "gray"
          },
          "strokeWidth": {
            "value": 1
          }
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {
            "field": "sourceX"
          },
          "y": {
            "field": "sourceY"
          },
          "x2": {
            "field": "targetX"
          },
          "y2": {
            "field": "targetY"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "symbol",
      "from": {
        "data": "filteredNodes"
      },
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {
            "field": "x"
          },
          "y": {
            "field": "y"
          },
          "size": {
            "value": 50
          },
          "stroke": {
            "value": "steelblue"
          },
          "fill": {
            "value": "white"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {
        "data": "filteredNodes"
      },
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {
            "field": "x",
            "offset": 5
          },
          "y": {
            "field": "y"
          },
          "text": {
            "field": "label"
          },
          "fontSize": {
            "value": 10
          },
          "align": {
            "value": "left"
          },
          "baseline": {
            "value": "middle"
          },
          "fill": {
            "value": "black"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {
    "range": {
      "category": {
        "scheme": "elastic"
      }
    },
    "arc": {
      "fill": "#54B399"
    },
    "area": {
      "fill": "#54B399"
    },
    "line": {
      "stroke": "#54B399"
    },
    "path": {
      "stroke": "#54B399"
    },
    "rect": {
      "fill": "#54B399"
    },
    "rule": {
      "stroke": "#54B399"
    },
    "shape": {
      "stroke": "#54B399"
    },
    "symbol": {
      "fill": "#54B399"
    },
    "trail": {
      "fill": "#54B399"
    },
    "title": {
      "color": "#343741"
    },
    "style": {
      "guide-label": {
        "fill": "#69707d"
      },
      "guide-title": {
        "fill": "#343741"
      },
      "group-title": {
        "fill": "#343741"
      },
      "group-subtitle": {
        "fill": "#343741"
      }
    },
    "axis": {
      "tickColor": "#eef0f3",
      "domainColor": "#eef0f3",
      "gridColor": "#eef0f3"
    },
    "background": "transparent"
  }
}

